# geolocation Aware iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, geolocation

I am developing a hybrid app using Ionic. Is it possible to have my app to be geolocation aware on iOS platform even when the app is not launched? I know this can be done with background service on Android. But can it be done on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

The Core Location framework can do background geofencing (with the user's permission). Have a look at the [Core Location Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123) and [Ray Wenderlich's geofencing guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift).

Specifically you probably want to use the [region monitoring methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW61) of `CLLocationManager`.